# Javascript table with amount of chosen rows and columns

Tags: javascript

practicing javascript trying to make a table where the user can choose amount of rows and columns but can figure it out..
[image]

What I have go so far:

```
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var row = table.insertRow(0);

    for(var i = 0; i < kolommen; i++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    }
```

Witch gives the amount of columns correctly.
[image]

Thereby I thought I could make a loop for the row to, like:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < rijen; i++){
        var row = table.insertRow(i);

        for(var i = 0; i < kolommen; i++){
            var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        }       
    }
```

witch gives the same effect, only 1 row..
The code I use is from:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp
Google around, tried some things from stackoverflow to but cant get it working. Does someone sees it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the variable `i` for both loops, making them conflict. You could for example use `i` for the row loop and `j` for the column loop.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above answer, once second loop completes, i value would be of second loops length and would fail to insertRow(i) in first loop since there is missing indices. Try a different variable in second loop as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rijen; i++){
    var row = table.insertRow(i);

    for(var j = 0; j < kolommen; j++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    }       
}
```

Comment: I thought that I already tried different variable names; j.
Thanks for al your responses. They al work!

Answer (score 1):

You used the same variable in two nested loops.

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="table" border=1> </table>

<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table');

    var count_Col, quant_Col, tag_Col, 
        count_Row, quant_Row, tag_Row;

    quant_Row = 5;
    quant_Col = 7;
    for (count_Row=0; count_Row < quant_Row; count_Row++)
    {
        tag_Row = table.insertRow(count_Row);

        for(count_Col=0; count_Col < quant_Col; count_Col++)
        {
            tag_Col = tag_Row.insertCell(count_Col);
            tag_Col.innerHTML = count_Col*count_Row;
        }       
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```